# Unable to retrieve data through eventBus in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a section in my vuejs where i'm attempting to send my reviews (in the form) to a `product-tabs` component through an `eventBus`. It seems that the reviews just refused to show. Would any one be able to help me understand why sending data through eventBus doesn't work?

**main.js**

```
var eventBus = new Vue()

Vue.component('product-tabs', { 
    props: {
        reviews: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <span class="tab"
                :class="{ activeTab: selectedTab === tab}"
                v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index"
                @click="selectedTab = tab">
                {{tab}}</span>
    
        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Reviews'">
            <p v-if="!reviews.length">There are no reviews yet.</p>
            <ul v-else>
                <li v-for="(review, index) in reviews" :key="index">
                    <p>{{ review.name }}</p>
                    <p>Rating:{{ review.rating }}</p>
                    <p>{{ review.review }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <product-review v-show="selectedTab === 'Make a review'"></product-review> 
    </div>
    `,
    data() { 
        return { 
            tabs: ['Reviews', 'Make a review'],
            selectedTab: 'Reviews'
        }
    }

})

Vue.component('product-review', { 
    template: `
        <!-- submit the form only if it is filled --> 
        <form class="review-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <p v-if="errors.length">
                <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
                </ul> 
            </p>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input id="name" v-model="name" placeholder="name">
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="review">Review:</label>
                <textarea id="review" v-model="review"></textarea>
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
                <!-- .number is a modifier that makes sure typecast is a number --> 
                <select id="rating" v-model.number="rating">
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <fieldset> 
                    <legend>Would you recommend this product?</legend>
                    <input class="" type="radio" name="recommend" v-model="recommend" value="yes">Yes
                    <input class="" type="radio" name="recommend" v-model="recommend" value="no">No
                </fieldset>
            </p>
                
            <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
            </p>    
        </form>
    `,
    data() {
        return { 
            name: null,
            review: null,
            rating: null,
            recommend: null,
            errors: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            if(this.name && this.review && this.rating && this.recommend) {
                let productReview = {
                    name: this.name,
                    review: this.review,
                    rating: this.rating,
                    recommend: this.recommend,
                    error: []
                }
                eventBus.$emit('review-submitted', productReview)
                this.name = null
                this.review = null
                this.rating = null
                this.recommend = null
            } else { 
                if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.")
                if(!this.review) this.errors.push("Review required.")
                if(!this.rating) this.errors.push("Rating required.")
                if(!this.recommend) this.errors.push("Recommendation required.")
            }
        }

    }
})


Vue.component('product', {
    props: {
        premium: {
            required: true,
            type: Boolean
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div class="product"> 
        <div id="product-image">
            <!-- bind the value of image in data object to src in our img tag-->
            <img class="product-image" v-bind:src="image" v-bind:alt="altText">
            <a v-bind:href="vbindDoc"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="product-info">
            <span class="allmyText">
                <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
                <p v-show="inStock">In stock</p>
                <span v-show='onSale'>
                    <p>{{ isOnSale }}</p>
                </span>
                <p>Shipping charges: {{ isShipping }}</p> 
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
                </ul>
                <div v-for="(variant, index) in variants" 
                    :key="variant.variantId"
                    class="color-box"
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }"
                    @mouseover="updateProduct(index)">
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
        <button class="cart" v-on:click="addToCart" 
                            :disabled="!inStock"
                            :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"
                            >Add to cart</button>
        <button class="cart" v-on:click="removeFromCart"
                                :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"
                                >Remove from cart</button>
        <!-- when there is stock, add a text-decoration: line-through; 
        This is done by binding a class -->
        <p :class="{ outofStock: inStock}">Out of stock</p>
        
        <product-tabs :reviews="reviews"></product-tabs>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            product: "Socks",
            brand: "Alan's branded",
            description: "A pair of warm and fuzzy",
            selectedVariant: 0,
            altText: "A pair of socks",
            vbindDoc: "https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/attribute-binding",
            onSale: true,
            details: ["80% Cotton", "20% polyesterer", "Gender-neutral"],
            variants: [
                {
                    variantId: 2232,
                    variantColor: "green",
                    variantImage: "https://www.vuemastery.com/images/challenges/vmSocks-green-onWhite.jpg",
                    variantQuantity: 10
                },
                {
                    variantId: 2233,
                    variantColor: "blue",
                    variantImage: "https://www.vuemastery.com/images/challenges/vmSocks-blue-onWhite.jpg",
                    variantQuantity: 5
                }
            ],
            sizes: [
                "small",
                "medium",
                "large"
            ],
            reviews: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            this.$emit('add-to-cart', this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantId)
        },
        removeFromCart() {
            this.$emit('remove-from-cart', this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantId)
        },
        updateProduct(index) {
            this.selectedVariant = index
            console.log(index)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        title() {
            return this.brand + " " + this.product
        },
        image() {
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
        },
        inStock() {
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity
        },
        isOnSale() {
            return this.brand + " " + this.product + " is on sale"
        },
        isShipping() {
            if (this.premium) {
                return "Free"
            } else {
                return 8.88
            }
        },
        mounted() { 
            eventBus.$on('review-submitted', productReview => {
                this.reviews.push(productReview)
            })
        }
    }
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        premium: false,
        cart: []
    },
    methods: {
        updateCart(id) {
            this.cart.push(id)
        },
        removeFromCart(id) {
            if (this.cart.length >= 1) {
                this.cart.shift(id)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <product :premium="premium" @add-to-cart="updateCart" @remove-from-cart="removeFromCart"></product> 
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{cart.length}})</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Take it from this url https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src='./main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 600px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  color: #282828;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #84cf6a, #16c0b0);
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 480px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 1px #d8d8d8;
}

#product-image {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

#product-info {
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.allmyText {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.color-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cart {
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1e95ea;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.disabledButton {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.review-form {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activeTab {
  color: #16c0b0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.outofStock {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

h2 { 
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Did you define `eventBus`?  It's being used but there's no definition in the code you posted.

Comment: Try, Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue()

Answer (score 0):

Your `mounted` function is inside the `computed` section. As such it'll be treated like a computed property and never invoked.

Try putting some console logging inside the `mounted` function. You should see that it is never called.

If you move the `mounted` function to be a top-level component option it should run fine.

As has already been noted in the comments you also don't appear to be defining `eventBus` anywhere. I would have thought that you would be getting error messages in the console if this were the case. Perhaps you just omitted it from the question?

If not then this also suggests that the `eventBus.$emit` line is never being hit. I suggest adding yet more console logging to establish exactly what lines are and are not being run. It shouldn't be difficult to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'll add a few console logs to  try. eventBus was added, it didn't seem to show in the output, and i've made a few tiny tweaks in my post to make it show now.

Moving the mounted function solved my problem. Thank you, skirtle!